# Recaptcha hostname validation

Tags: recaptcha

I'm trying to verify hostname field that goes in response from google (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request)

Most of the times everuthing is ok, but sometimes I get empty hostname or hostname with value "www.google.com" but not my host.

The question is how google determines the hostname and why it may be empty or "google.com". Or it's ok?